# How to get common word for a specific column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, intersection, string-concatenation

I have a dataset, which contains two column with the same name 'Name', i want to make a new column 'Intersection' which contains only the common word from the two columns Name, i tried using various merge or list functions but i am not getting it, Can anyone please help? Here is my data https://github.com/mayuripandey/Data-Analysis/blob/main/output.csv [image]

Answer (score 0):

> tried using various merge or list functions

You need to use [`set.intersection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) method. You would first need to extract words into some iterable to use said methods, consider following example

```
import re
text_1 = "Hello World!"
text_2 = "World of Tomorrow?"
words_1 = re.findall(r'\w+',text_1)
words_2 = re.findall(r'\w+',text_2)
common = set(words_1).intersection(words_2)
print(common) # {'World'}
```

Note that I assumed you understand word as 1 or more word character in [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) understanding and that you want to work in case-sensitive mode (therefore `world`, `World` and `WORLD` are different words). If latter does not hold true use [`casefold`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) method of `str` before processing as described above.